# function that changes the position of 2 elements in a list

Tags: python, list, function

I have to write a function that will work if I write this:

```
s = ["John", "Bertha", "Janna", "Daniel", "Emma"]
change(s,2,4)
print(s)
["John", "Bertha", "Emma", "Daniel", "Janna"]
```

I basically have to define a function that changes the position of 2 elements in a list where `a, b` are their indexes.

I've tried doing it like this, but I can't seem to find a good solution:

```
def change(s,a,b):
    a,b = s.index(a), s.index(b)
    s[b], s[a] = s[a], s[b]
```

This obviously doesn't work, I have no idea how I can change the position of 2 elements where `a, b` are their indexes, I know how to switch 2 items, but no clue how to do it with a function.. how does one go on about this one?

Comment: If you *already have* the indices, why are you calling `index`?! Try `print(a, b)` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are the *indexes* of the items that you need to switch.  If you already know where they are, then you can (should) remove the calls to `list.index`:

```
>>> s = ["John", "Bertha", "Janna", "Daniel", "Emma"]
>>> def change(s, a, b):
...     s[b], s[a] = s[a], s[b]
...
>>> change(s, 2, 4)
>>> s
['John', 'Bertha', 'Emma', 'Daniel', 'Janna']
>>>
```